# Unable to see newer Nuget packages. The old ones are still there

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-server

I have a Nuget package manager on our local server.

The restore process of the pipeline in Azure Dev Ops attempts to fetch the packages, however it is unable to see the latest ones.

We had a major DNS/Firewall issue last week and since then I am unable to check in any code because the process fails to find the latest packages.

However, confusingly it can see all the older packages added before the outage. So I presume they are somehow cached?

I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this so any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit to add** - The problem has appeared to have fixed itself.
I presume it was related to caching as the comment by @rickvdbosch seemed to suggest. I did look through the linked documentation and was unable to locate the cache items.
I am leaving the question open as I would rather know what happened and it may be useful for someone else coming across this situation.

Comment: You probably first need to make sure all DNS/Firewall issues have been solved. As far as NuGet (local) cache goes, see this: [Managing the global packages, cache, and temp folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/Consume-Packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

Comment: @rickvdbosch As far as I know the DNS/Firewall issues were fixed... I can push packages and install them albeit from within the confines of the local network. Would you be inclined to think that there may be remaining issues accessing the packages outside of the network?
Thanks for your comment.